# reset jQuery-mousemove when mouse is no longer hovering over div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

I was looking for a `parallax mousemove script` the other day and found this script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div1').mousemove(function (e) {
        parallax(e, this, 0.5);
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('div2'), 1);
        parallax(e, document.getElementById('div3'), 1.5);
    });
});

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
    var layer_coeff = 10 / layer;
    var x = ($(window).width() - target.offsetWidth) / 2 - (e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
    var y = ($(window).height() - target.offsetHeight) / 2 - (e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
    $(target).offset({ top: y ,left : x });
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to reset the script to the default position when the mouse is no longer hovering over `div1`. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. If there is a better `Script` for this purpose feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer, but this would probably still achieve your goal in a minimal way,

using `css` and `transition` effects onhover of your `div`.

See Sample Code.

Using CSS alone,

```
.yourDiv{
   /* Put your default styling here */
   transition:2s;
}

.yourDiv:hover{
   /* Put your hover effect here */
   margin-left:10px;
   transition:2s;
}
```

On mouseOut on your div, it will display your div in its default styling with transition effect.